# CRM Dynamics 2015, Trigger Plugin on mobile phone fields click

Tags: c#, plugins

I have a plugin in CRM 2015, that I tested on create of a record, I need a way to trigger the plugin from clicking a button next to the phone number field, my plugin basically initiates a phone call, how can I accomplish this?. How do i trigger a plugin on a mobile fileds click, or perhaps a button next to the mobile phone filed to trigger the plugin, what is the best approach and is this possible.?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create an Action and develop plugin that handles it. Following articles could help you:

http://a33ik.blogspot.com/2013/10/custom-actions-walkthrough-for-net-and.html
http://a33ik.blogspot.com/2013/10/custom-actions-deployment-through-crm.html